# Colocar botão de evento para acessar página

Tags: javascript

Como coloco botão de evento para acessar a seguinte página:

No Html:

```
<a id="navMn">Blog</a>
```

Tenho o seguinte código javascript, que está com erro:

```
function abreOjnl(){
    window.open('../menu/blog.html');
}

document.getElementById('navMn').addEventListener('click', abreOjnl);
```

Comment: Leandro, conseguiu realizar o que queria usando o <a href=" ?

Answer (score 3):

Por que você não usa o `<a href="../menu/blog.html" id="navMn">Blog</a>` ?

Comment: Usando assim fica bem mais simples!

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que você está tentando abrir uma nova janela do `navegador` sem passar uma `URL` como parâmetro.

Do jeito que estás a usar, não é possível pois a função não irá entender o caminho solicitado.

Tente da seguinte maneira:

```
window.open('http://seuhost.com/menu/blog.html')
```

Se for local:

```
window.open('http://127.0.0.1:porta/menu/blog.html')
```

Comment: não dá pra usar http, por que o diretório está na pasta do pc e não na rede kk

Comment: mais conseguir resolver trocando a extenção para php e abrir com xxamp https://localhost mais mesmo assim valeu :)

Comment: @Leandro Lobo conseguiu resolver?